# Android Programming - Always Restarts same Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am using Android Studio for a simple communication app and this definitly might be a stupid question but I couldn't find the answer to it yet.

I am simply starting a new intent on a button click. However, the very first time the user does this, he is asked what kind of app he wants to use. Therefore, there are at least two applications with the same intent filter, namely "ACTION_VIEW"

**My Problem:**

After the initial click the button always "reuses" his initial choice so the user does not have a decision anymore which app he wants to use for this intent.
Unfortunately, this is excactly what I want. The user should get the chance to select the app of his favor each time he clicks on the button.

The relevant part of code is as simple as follows:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an [App Chooser](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser) to show the dialog for the user to choose which app to use each time:

> [I]f the action to be performed could be handled by multiple apps and the user might prefer a different app each time—such as a "share" action, for which users might have several apps through which they might share an item—you should explicitly show a chooser dialog.... The chooser dialog forces the user to select which app to use for the action every time (the user cannot select a default app for the action).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
...

// Always use string resources for UI text.
// This says something like "Share this photo with"
String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
// Create intent to show chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18503227)

Comment: @ThomasSmyth That is a good point. I copied the code example here to (hopefully) improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly and is exactly what I have searched for.

Comment: @malill please accept my answer by clicking on the check. When you have enough reputation, you can also vote answers which you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` could probably help you.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html